# Unexpected Empty Query Result in MarkLogic

Tags: sparql, marklogic

Executing the following SparQL query for example will cause a empty query result in MarkLogic:

```
SELECT *
WHERE { ?s ?p ?o .
        FILTER ( 805964266*1719307142*805964270 )
      }
```

#### Expected query result:

The all data in the database.

#### Alternatives:

Executing the SparQL query in Query Console and with Java Client API will both get empty query result.

This query can return the expected query result in Apache Jena and RDF4j.

Can someone give me an answer or a hint about it?

Comment: What is the purpose of that `FILTER`? Were you intending for the effective boolean value to be true? Why such a large number and computed value? In XQuery that expression produces a decimal overflow: `XDMP-DECOVRFLW: (err:FOAR0002) 805964266 * 1719307142 * 805964270 -- Decimal overflow` and in JavaScript it produces a Number: `1.11682478463161E27`.

Comment: While xsd:integer is unlimited, the XPath Functions and Operators spec allows implementations to have limitations and raise an exception. https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#op.numeric. So no triples because FILTER raises an error and ""error" is false.

Apache Jena uses Java's `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that the expression: `805964266*1719307142*805964270` is producing a decimal overflow. If you execute that expression by itself as XQuery it produces the following error:

> [1.0-ml] XDMP-DECOVRFLW: (err:FOAR0002) 805964266 * 1719307142 * 805964270 -- Decimal overflow

If you explicitly evaluate those numbers as `xs:double` values, then it will compute a value and the applied `FILTER` produces the expected results:

```
PREFIX xs: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
SELECT *
WHERE { ?s ?p ?o .
        FILTER (  xs:double(805964266)*xs:double(1719307142)*xs:double(805964270) )
      }
```

For additional information about **XDMP-DECOVERFLW**, refer to this knowledgebase article:

https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/163/0/decimal-division-error-xdmp-decovrflw